# What mount is this 1.5 inch Taylor & Hobson Super Comat f1.9 16mm movie lens?

Tags: canon, canon-m

I bought this lens described as `C` mount and I bought a `C` to `EOS M` adapter, but the screw mount is too small for the inner diameter of the adapter as pictured here.

Can you please help me identify this mount?
Is this a `D` mount? If so, how can I mount it on my EOS M?

[image: not quit sure if it is D mount or not]

Comment: Would be helpful if you add a photo of the mount without the adapter obscuring it.